# A person who comes to stay in a hotel is said to be

Tags: word-choice, word-request

A person who comes from a far off place and stays in a hotel is said to be a guest in my view. But another of our senior teacher rejected this word. So, Is it a right term? Or any other proper word could be there.

Comment: The word for a person who stays at a hotel is **guest**, but the guest might live in the same city where the hotel is located, or the guest could have traveled across an ocean.  The word **guest** is agnostic about the distance the guest has traveled.  Your teacher may be emphasizing the travel, and may be looking for **tourist**.  But there's no guarantee that a tourist will stay at a hotel. A tourist might stay at a B&B.  :)

Comment: _A hotel guest_ is a good word.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a hotel and you have visitors who might come there and possibly stay there are called many things, out of which '**guests**' is the best word. You could use a few words such as:

> - Customer
> - Traveler
> - Tourists
> - Tenant

But all these suggestions have conditions that may not qualify them as a perfect synonym for the word *'guests'* in this context.

I have to disagree with your teacher and I suggest you ask him what he would've used for that particular context. Maybe you didn't interpret what he meant properly.

Answer (score 0):

While the alternatives can be useful in some circumstances, I personally would prefer the word `patron` most of the time. A ***patron*** is

> a person who is a customer, client, or paying guest, especially a regular one, of a store, hotel, or the like. ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/patron))